# Is there a way to dynamically import a TypeScript `type` in a React component?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Let's say I have the following example code. The usage of this shared component will have different valid `name` props depending on where the component is used. Is it possible to dynamically import `TYPE_IMPORT` so that it imports the appropriate type when used in a different context.

```ts
// example/import/path1.ts
export type TYPE_IMPORT = "foo" | "bar" | "testing1" | "testing2";
```

```ts
// example/import/path2.ts
export type TYPE_IMPORT = "pikachu" | "charmander" | "testing3" | "testing4";
```

```tsx
import { TYPE_IMPORT } from 'example/import/path1';

interface IFooProps {
  name: TYPE_IMPORT;
}

export const FooComponent = (props: IFooProps ) => {
  const { name} = props;

  return (
    <svg>
      <use href={`#${name}`} />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: You should look into TypeScript's [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), they're probably the best approach for this kind of pattern

Comment: @Phil, sorry! Bad copy pasta. It's `name`. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate the type to consuming code using generics

```tsx
interface ISvgProps<T> {
  name: T;
}

export const SvgComponent = <T extends string>({ name }: ISvgProps<T>) => (
  <svg>
    <use href={`#${name}`} />x
  </svg>
);
```

Then use whatever type you want

```tsx
import { TYPE_IMPORT as FooType } from 'example/import/path1';
import { TYPE_IMPORT as PokemonType } from 'example/import/path2';

const FooComponent = SvgComponent<FooType>;
const PokemonComponent = SvgComponent<PokemonType>;

// ...

return (
  <>
    <FooComponent name="foo" />
    <PokemonComponent name="pikachu" />
  </>
);
```